# while loop menu keep looping second menu

Tags: python, while-loop

- If I **choose 1** for the first time, and then **choose 1** again for the second time,
- and then **choose 2** on the second menu to return back to the first menu
- and I **choose quit** but it will show second menu again.
- I have to **choose 2** for three times then the program will close.

It must be something wrong with my while loop but I cannot find it :(

```
def menu(): # first menu
    print('+----------------------------+')
    print('|        first menu here     |')
    print('+----------------------------+')
    print('|choose [1]                  |')
    print('+----------------------------+')
    print('|choose [2] to quit          |')
    print('+----------------------------+')
    return input('>> ')

def s_menu(): # second menu
    print('+**********************************+')
    print('|       second menu here           |')
    print('+**********************************+')
    print('|choose [1] to continue            |')
    print('+**********************************+')
    print('|choose [2] to back first menu     |')
    print('+**********************************+')
    return input('>> ')

def doSomething():
    print('Something here')

    second_while()  # declare second s_menu() here

def second_while(): # loop second s_menu()
    while True:
        resp = s_menu()
        if resp == '1':
            doSomething()
        elif resp == '2':
            menu()
            break
        else:
            print('Wrong input!')
        #break  # if break was here, wrong user input will close terminal immediately


# loop first menu()
while True:
    inp = menu()
    if inp == '1':
        doSomething()
    elif inp == '2':
        print('Break')
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong input!')
    #break  # if break was here, wrong user input will close terminal immediately
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I have found the solution for my answer. While loop inside the while loop

```
# loop first menu()
while True:
    menu()
    inp = input('>> ')
    if inp == '1':
        doSomething()
        # loop doSomething()
        while True:
            resp = input('>> ')
            if resp == '1':
                doSomething()
            elif resp == '2':
                break
            else:
                print('Wrong input')
    elif inp == '2':
        print('Break')
        break
    else:
        print('Wrong input!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
def doSomething():
    print('Something here')

    second_while()  # declare second s_menu() here
```

to

```
def doSomething():
    print('Something here')
```

Otherwise every time you call `doSomething()`, you go 1 layer of `second_while()` deeper, and will need to press **2** one more time to exit all of them.

Comment: If I'm doing this ```def doSomething(): print('Something here')``` it will not show second menu. Second menu is an option for user to run ```doSomething``` one more if the user want to, if not user can choose 2 to return back to the first menu.

Comment: Oh, right. Simply add a call to `second_while()` after `doSomething()` in the first menu.